# A question on the short multiplets at the threshold

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, superconformality

In a few articles that I read namely this one: [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to
4d $\cal N = 2$ Superconformal Field Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14764)

people talk about the so-called **null states**. The discussion continues till it introduces the **short multiplet at the threshold** where it is mentioned in equation 2.8 that $l=1,2$. Given equation 2.5, where does the restriction on $l$ come from?

Oppositely, in the following paper: [Multiplets of Superconformal
Symmetry in Diverse Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00809)
 in equation 1.11 the authors say that $l$ can be any non-negative integer. Why is that? Is this the particular case of $\mathfrak{su}(2,2|2)$ that limits $l$ to 1,2? if so how?

Comment: The (super)conformal algebra dictates that certain descendants have to vanish if the scaling dimension of the primary becomes too small. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00809 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563571/recombination-phenomena-in-cft/644041

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for the paper. Honestly, I read also the same paper but in equation 1.11 the range of $l$ is all non-negative integers in contrast to the paper I attached. What's the reason? Does it have to do with the particular case of $\mathfrak{su}(2,2|2)$? Then how?

Comment: CDI were not trying to claim that all non-negative integer values for $l$ would be realized. As page 33 shows, there are two A-type shortening conditions in 4d. The highest this number can go across all dimensions is 4.

Comment: I see, but I can't still see the reason for $l$ to be at most 2 in this particular case of $\mathfrak{su}(2,2|2)$  @ConnorBehan

Comment: What does it mean for $l = 3$ to not be allowed? It means that for all states of the schematic form $Q^3 \left | \Delta \right >$, zeros of its norm occur at values of $\Delta$ which make $Q^2 \left | \Delta \right >$ or $Q^1 \left | \Delta \right >$ type norms strictly negative. I'm not sure there is a more succinct reason.

Comment: No. Long multiplets allow you to act with all the $Q$s. So there are certainly large enough values of $\Delta$ such that $Q^1 \left | \Delta \right >$, $Q^2 \left | \Delta \right >$ and $Q^3 \left | \Delta \right >$ all have positive norm. When you are looking for shortening conditions though it's a different story.